# How can I put a line in the foreground so that it is always recognisable in large data clouds?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Good morning everyone,

I have a simple problem that I have not been able to solve for about an hour now. I hope you can help me quickly here and comfort me a little and say "don't worry, you will learn". :)

I am building a relatively complex diagram in which measurement data with a large scatter are represented as points and I want to draw a line across them so that they can be easily recognised.

Apparently it is now the case that the points are always preferred (foreground) in the representation. It does not matter whether the curve or the points are first.

Enclosed is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
0           10 \\
1000   25  \\
2000   30  \\
3000   40   \\
4000   50   \\
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    xmin=0, xmax=4000,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 280,
        width=0.65\linewidth,height=0.65\linewidth
}


\begin{axis}[
                            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                            xtick={0,500,...,4000},
                        ]
                                                    
                            \addplot [color=red,mark=asterisk,only marks] table [x index ={0}, y index = {1}, col sep=comma] {\mytable}; %10
                            \addplot [color=black,solid] table [x index ={0}, y index = {1}, col sep=comma] {\mytable}; %10
                            
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{H}
\label{fig:H}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**How can I now put the line in the foreground so that it is always recognisable in large data clouds?**

My real data:
[image: My Data]

Greetings

Parsec

Comment: Probably putting the line with `\addplot[color=red]` _after_ the plot in black would be sufficient?

Comment: @ Marijn: No, unfortunately that didn't work. With simple lines, the line change works. It seems that "mark" is always preferred and placed on the top layer. At least that's what my experiments have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem just hasn't left me alone.
I had an inspiration and have now found a solution.

I have installed a second axis for the curve and set this "axis on top". This now does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Can you please add some compilable TeX code showing your solution for a fast proof?